# Generating a thumbnail as a button in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I was wondering why my button is creating a border around my thumbnail even though I styled it so that it would have no borders at all?

css style:

```
.modalButton: {
  padding: ['0rem', '0rem'];
  backgroundColor: '#568db2';
  border: 0;
  borderRadius: '0rem';
  fontSize: '0rem';
  color: '#fff';
  cursor: 'pointer';
  marginBottom: '0rem';
}
```

code:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true })}
  className="modalButton"
>
  <Thumbnail src={snapshot} />
</button>
```

even though it is supposed to generate the picture without any borders and is supposed to look just like an ordinary thumbnail, it actually gives me this when it's rendered:

[rendered picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCsli.png)

is there a problem with my code?

EDIT:
[inspected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmkrQ.png)

when I inspect the image it gives me

```
<div> == $0
```

[styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiaem.png)

[styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SQaE.jpg)

and this is the styles that it says it has. Is there a way to change it?

[EDIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuOVS.jpg)

[With new line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDjSB.jpg)

[padding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgKrc.jpg)

[image box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyviM.jpg)

Comment: Using chrome developer tools, you can check what styles are being applied to a particular element. You can use that to even see where those styles are being inherited from. Do that, maybe you'll have some idea why that border is being applied.

Comment: Can you post a picture inspecting it ?

Comment: @karthik added a picture inspecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the images, Here is whats happening, Turns out your button(Image) is having these properties border-color, border-style, border-width which your thumbnail is inhering add the below class to your style. Hope this will fix,

```
.thumbnail{
    border-color:initial !important;
    border-style:initial !important;
    border-width:initial !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I added it to my styles page but it only removed the border. After changing the names of the buttons and the styling the button does not change at all. Is there a problem with how I am adding the style to the button itself? All I need to do is make the white part of the button be transparent so that only the thumbnail of the image appears to be there.

Comment: That bottom space is because of the button padding try the edit ... this will remove the extra bottom space if that is what you want ?

Comment: when I added it, it just removed the top part. Is it possible to simply make it transparent?

Comment: try adding `-webkit-appearance:` none; or  `background-color: transparent;` .... can't grantee though i can help you better if i can inspect it live ..

Comment: Omg I didn't realize that I had formatted the style sheet actually wrong so it wasn't registering the code that I had put in it. The background-color: transparent; also worked thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is to look at what styles are being applied to the element with the developer tools in a popular browser.

Some things to note when dealing with borders:

1. The box-sizing settings applied: [CSS Box-Sizing Property](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)
2. The CSS outline property: [CSS Outline Property](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_outline.asp)

Both of which can have surprising and potentially frustrating affects for the unwary developer;

Here is a quote from W3Schools addressing the outline/border confusion:

> Outline differs from borders! Unlike border, the outline is drawn outside the element's border, and may overlap other content. Also, the outline is NOT a part of the element's dimensions; the element's total width and height is not affected by the width of the outline.